# A beginner here asking about Java class and function

Tags: java, function, class

So my question is when do you decide to make it as a function or a new class. For instance if I am writing a program to reverse the string. I can do it either using a function called Reverse(char* str) or a class name Reverse. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean function and not method? They are both valid but different.

Comment: Perhaps ask this question again in a more specific way using some code examples. Also you appear to be confusing c or c++ with java (`char*` and `function`)

Comment: oops mixed with c a bit and yeah I am asking function and class and thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Java is a class/object (well, almost everything). You can not just create a function reverse() somewhere on its own without wrapping it with a class.

So the question should be more like: do I extend my current class/object with a new method to allow to e.g. reverse a value in the class or do I use an existing method from an already existing class?

Classes are entities to group methods/functions by a specific use-case.

Comment: I think assuming they're speaking about Java and any application needs a class that they mean they could have a method in *that* class which handles the reverse for the program. Though I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do more reading on basic object oriented concepts to get detail idea on when to design something as a class and as a method.

For now, I'll answer at basic level.

Class is something which you see as an entity. For example car,place,cycle etc. Class has properties and may provide some services. These services are essentially methods.

In your case, reverse is a service provided by your class. Hence it should be modeled as a method (or function as you called it). Sometimes it helps to have basic rule in mind. Any noun is usually good candidate for a class. And any verb is usually a good candidate for a method.

So reverse is a verb - hence a method/function. Again this is just a rule of thumb and you should develop a sense of what it means by reading and practicing more.